# How can I set cookies when running Apify locally?

Tags: apify

After a lot of Googling, I'm at a loss of how to set cookies for a Puppeteer Apify crawler using raw cookies (i.e. `name1=value1; name2=value2; ...`)

I see that there's `Page.SetCookie`, but that requires an array of Puppeteer.Cookie objects. Really difficult to format this every time.

I also see that Apify supports setting cookies on the Apify Dashboard. But this isn't helpful (I don't think at least, maybe I'm wrong) if I want to run my application locally.

If there's any way of accomplishing this, I'd love to know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need a simple converter from the raw cookies to the array that works with [setCookie](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.2.1&show=api-pagesetcookiecookies).

If your format is this simple, just do

```
const rawCookies = "name1=value1; name2=value2";

const cookiesArray = rawCookies
                         .split(';')
                         .map((rawCookie) => {
                              const [name, value] = rawCookie.trim().split('=');
                              return {
                                  name, 
                                  value,
                              };
                         });
```

For anything more complicated, there will be [libraries](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=cookie).